# Best way of dealing with a common/central object

Tags: java

I have a program where I need to read and write data to a common (central?) object from most other obejcts. In a way it acts like a database or perhaps databus if you like. I cannot write it to a file. Currently I do it like this:

```
class A {
    private Common common;
    private B b;
    
    public A() {
        common = new Common();
        b = new B(common);
    }
}

class B {
    private Common common;
    private C c;

    public B(Common common) {
        this.common = common;
        c = new C(common);
    }
}

class C {
    private Common common;
    private D d;

    public C(Common common) {
        this.common = common;
        d = new D(common);
    }
}


...etc.
```

So I am passing the object "down the line" but it feels wrong doing it like this (given the amount of objects I am getting to). Is there a better way of doing this?

Edit: Class A can be instantiated multiple times, so Common is only common for all the objects in each individual A.

Comment: Do you know the term "singleton"? Do you have some IoC / DI library in place?

Comment: You could consider implementing it like Serializable, so have a common "Writable" interface which object like B and C implement exposing their attributes that can be written. Then you can have a "writer" which takes in "Writable" as an input parameter to a function and does the writing.

Comment: @luk2302 I know the term, but I can have multiple Objects A each with their own common object. Afaik a singleton wouldn't work then? I am relativly new to OOP, so I may be mistaken.

Comment: I think the suggestion was have Common be the singleton

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, but Common can be instantiated multiple times as well (once in each A). Or can a singleton have multiple instances like that?

Comment: @Scoprion That sounds a bit beyond my current understanding. I will look into it.

Comment: Ah... Can you give more examples of usages of A / Common? If you have multiple instances, then it's not really a "central" object

Comment: @OneCricketeer The simplest way to describe it is that Object A is a computer running 1 program. I can create multiple computers. Each computer has parts like CPU, Memory, IO, a Program (which has instruction), etc. and they all need R/W access to the RAM. (hence why I compared it to a databus).

Comment: This might also be a reason to have an inner class. If class B was an inner class of A, then it would automatically have access to A's common. It seems a bit odd to me that you have such a one directional chain, that all seem to start from `Common`. You could have a Common, and let that create instances of the objects you want. Eg. `public B getB()` as a method of Common.

Comment: @matt I simplified the example. It is not a lineair chain but it fans out. Think of Common as a spine with the nerves that carry signals through the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real answer is "don't".

You can use the `Singleton` pattern; but, by doing so you are avoiding "object oriented programming" which is the method that Java uses to make the programs maintainable and repairable.

Once you have a single, central object, you can't modify your code easily in many ways without investigating how the central object is impacted, and then investigating how all the other objects that also use the central object are impacted through the central object.

Instead create an object for each scenario.  This allows you to process two scenarios at a time, which will make life easier when you start to make your programs multi-threaded, something you'll want to do sooner or later, because otherwise you'll only use 1 core in that 8 core processor.

Your language assumes a central object, so I can't provide an example in your scenario.  I'll modify `Commmon` to `Context` where `Context` means "the scenario I'm dealing with now".

Note that with such a change, you probably shouldn't own the context, you should pass it along.

```
class A {
    private B b;
    
    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }

    public handle(Context context) {
        context.add(...whatever...);
        b.handle(context);
    }
}

class B {
    private C c;

    public B() {
        c = new C();
    }

    public handle(Context context) {
        context.remove(...whatever...);
        context.add(...something else...);
        c.handle(context);
    }
}

class C {
    private D d;

    public C() {
        d = new D();
    }

    public handle(Context context) {
        context.do(...whatever...);
        d.handle(context);
    }
}
```

The way to call this is now

```
Context c1 = new Context();
Context c2 = new Context();
A a = new A();
a.handle(c1);
a.handle(c2);
```

And as you can see, there's no longer a need for a single "central" class.

Fitting the problem into the language, or selecting the language for the problem is a learned skill.  Please avoid Singleton, as it is a hard learned anti-pattern, one that hurts software maintainability.

If you wrote all of your code with Singletons, the code could easily be ported into a non-object oriented language (like C, FORTRAN, etc) because Singletons are syntatic sugar for "global scope, with slightly better name spaces".  The reason that C++, Java, etc became popular was due to the easier code maintenance of structuring code into Objects.

Comment: Generally, constructing objects that are to be shared inside a class that uses it creates more problems (singleton or not) unless the object is only shared within the scope of the class that constructed it.  Even then it can make maintenance issues.

Comment: I like this answer, many advicate for singletone, but I would advice not to use (however it's worth to learn what it is). Also I would get rid of tightly coupled objects. It's good practice, not to create a new instance inside of objects, but rather pass it as a constructor parameter. For example: `B b = new B(); A a = new A(b);` Ideally you constructor should do nothing but init fields, i.e. there should be no `new` operator inside the constructor.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. It does mean a rewrite and another way of organising it. But that is fine. Thank you TIL.

Comment: @Bert You have the idea 100%.  You still have the object holding the data, and you pass it down the line.  This approach permits many similar objects to be passed down the line.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing such objects, and not passing them as argument as methods, you need to have something that **provides you the instance**. That something can

- create the instance **initially or on-demand**
- use a single instance, or provide **context-sensitive** instances (e.g. one per thread, or by tenant, by user, and so on)

### Singleton Pattern

The base *Design Pattern* for such an object is the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), where the (single) instance is created and provided by the class of that instance.

The usage would look like this:

```
Common common = Common.instance();
```

### Registry Pattern

When more advanced pattern for such objects is the **Registry pattern** (see *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture* by Martin Fowler), where a dedicated singleton (the registry) creates and provides these instances.

The usage would look like this:

```
Common common = Registry.instance().get(Common.class);
```

### Dependency Injection

Frameworks such as **JavaEE (CDI)** and **Spring** leverage the registry pattern, and use a Bean Registry to manage such instances, and supply them over **Dependency Injection**.

### Recommendation

- for simple cases/projects, use the Singleton pattern
- consider using the Spring Framework, CDI or something alike (Quarkus, Micronaut) for more sophisticated cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem that "dependency injection" frameworks like Guice are intended to solve. Many Java applications have a set of classes that model "the application," as opposed to the data that the application works on. The app might have a `Server`, and a `WidgetService`, and a `Database`, a `DatabaseWidgetReader`, and so on. These classes all collaborate with each other to implement the application logic, and each one is usually accepts its collaborators as constructor arguments.

But once you have more than a few such classes, and you have a big `initialize` method that constructs everything, and every test has to have its own version of the big `initialize` method, you start thinking that there must be a better way.

With a framework like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) you just annotate your constructor parameters with `@Inject`, provide some bootstrap configuration, and let the framework do the rest. To make your example work with Guice, you would:

1. Modify the class constructors to accept *all* of their collaborators as arguments. So for example, the `A` constructor should take both `Common` and `B`.
2. Create the "injector," which is basically a factory.
3. Tell the injector to bind the class `Common` to a specific instance that you create. (I'm assuming here that `Common` needs some information that it can't get from Guice, maybe the address of a database server.)
4. Ask the injector for an instance of one of the other classes.

Usually the class you specify in the last step will be something like `Server` or `Application` or something that is the entry point for the whole app.

Let's say you ask for `A` in the last step. Guice says, okay, I need a `Common`, which I have (provided in the third step above), and an instance of `B`. In order to get `B`, I need a `Common` and a `C`, etc. Obviously this chain has to end somewhere. Guice will trace out all the dependencies and construct everything, then return you the instance of `A`.

If you have some objects that you don't want to be singletons (e.g., you want to instantiate a new `CPU` every time you need one but want all `CPU` instances to share the same `Memory`) you can register a "provider" that Guice will use to create new instances.

There are other frameworks that work more or less the same way; I'm just most familiar with Guice.